# Access logic on JSON-Object from Backbone in HAML

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, haml

I want to loop over a backbone-generated JSON-Object in HAML

My View renders as follows:

```
render: function() {
  this.$el.html(this.template( this.model.toJSON() ))
  return this;
}
```

The this.model.toJSON() has the valeu:

```
Object {name: "E", data_set: "[{"value":"g"},{"value":"b"}]"}
```

My HAML Template looks like that:

```
%script#template{"type" => "text/template"}
  %div.chord
    %span <%= data_set %>
```

How can I achieve to iterate over the data-set, in order to access the two values "g" and "b" and display them in the template.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your view your template property will reference a JavaScript function that will compile your HAML template. [Refer to this site for a HAML to JavaScript function compiler](https://github.com/creationix/haml-js)

```
var x = Backbone.View.extend({
   template: Haml($("#TemplateName").html()), // <-- 
   render: function() {
     // now render your template out
   }
});
```

Hopefully this works for you. I haven't tested the code but the concept is universal in Backbone when you want to change the templating engine.  There also seems to be a couple of other HAML to JavaScript projects out there that you can look into.

Comment: Thx for the answer, I ended up using https://github.com/uglyog/clientside-haml-js for client side haml.